# How to take user input and put it in a new array within an array in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, nested-lists

I'm trying to put user input (just a list of ints) into a list that already exists with one element in it. I'm not sure if it's possible to have a list running off of one element in an already existing list. Might eventually add more elements to already existing list.

## Code below:

```
days = ["Monday"]

days[0] = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter your schedule: ").split()]

print(days)
```

I expected the results to give me a list within a list, but the actual result was:

```
days[0] = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter your schedule: ").split()]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1000,'
```

Comment: When you were asked to enter your schedule, what did you type? If you typed commas, don't type that. Just type `1000 2000 3000` or such with spaces.

Comment: So I did take out the commas from the input but I'm also trying to have Monday included in the array when it's printed out, so I changed days[0] to days[1] but now it's throwing me this error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I could try appending things, but I'm not sure how this works.

Comment: What do you want days to contain after you provide information like `1000 2000 3000` at command prompt?

Comment: I want days to look like ["Monday" [1000, 2000, 3000]] if that's even possible?

Comment: You will get ["Monday", [1000, 2000, 3000]] - notice the comma after "Monday". That works for you?

Comment: Is it not possible to have another list correlating to one element in a list? (that's what I was looking for originally)

Comment: Check out my updated answer that includes dictionary object. Dictionary allows you have a key-value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
days = ["Monday"]    
days.append( [int(x) for x in input("Please enter your schedule: ").split()] )
print(days)
```

That'll give you `["Monday", [1000, 2000, 3000]]` if you provided `1000 2000 3000` from command prompt.

If you do this:

```
days = ["Monday"]

input_data = input("Please enter your schedule: ")
split_data = input_data.split()
for item in split_data:
    days.append(item)
print(days)
```

You will get `["Monday", 1000, 2000, 3000]`

Or you can use dictionary like so:

```
days = {}
days["Monday"] = [int(x) for x in input("Please enter your schedule: ").split()]
print(days)
```

to get `{'Monday': [1000, 2000, 3000]}`

Comment: Thank you! I believe the last one is more optimal and closer to what I was looking for.